# Starvation on getting JDBC connection to DB

Tags: multithreading, jdbc

My application uses postgresql . I use PGPoolingDataSource with ~50 connections.

The problem I'm having is that getConnection is blocked until a connection is available. the application is very busy with thousands of DB calls. and so the thread that is waiting to get his connection never gets it (or gets it in 20-30 minutes) - This is called "Starvation" in multi threading.

I really want to avoid implementing my own connection threadpool that is based on a blocking queue. 
Perhaps there's a connection pool that grantees connection in FIFO (first in firt out) ? 
Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Can't you increase the pool size?

Comment: Playing around with queuing policies (FIFO, LIFO) will not help you. Take a look of [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/2014/04/17/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling/) which explains what happens when an application requests a JDBC connection and how the DB connection pool help. If your application has a lot of work to do while holding a DB connection (as is suggested from your question) than you should try to expand the DB connection capacity and/or improve DB query performance. I.e. to seek ways to minimize the queries processing times.

Comment: My application has a lot of work but each job is quite fast. I thought about it and came into the same conclusion  - FIFO\LIFO won't help, I would probably need a connection pool with priorities since there are calls that I don't mind if it takes hours but there calls that must execute fast.